# Conflict between two scripts for in-page anchor links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two small scripts that, when working alone, have no problems.

However, when appearing together in the same document, they fail to work properly.

***Script #1: Launch Modal Dialog Box***

All pages on my website have links to the following features:

- Login Page
- Contact Page
- E-mail Sign-Up

When a user clicks on one of these links, a lightbox appears and the relevant modal slides in.

To prevent the page from scrolling in the background when the lightbox is active, I have this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[href$='#contact'],[href$='#email'],[href$='#login']").click(function(){
      $("body").addClass("noscroll");
    });
    $("a[href$='#close']").click(function(){
      $("body").removeClass("noscroll");
    });    
});
```

The CSS is simply:

```
.noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This function works perfectly, as far as I can tell.

***Script #2: Smooth Scrolling***

I have several web pages with long content (e.g., Terms of Service, Privacy Policy, etc.)

To make these pages more user-friendly, I've added a table of contents on the top. Each item in the TOC is an anchor link leading to the relevant section on the page.

Example:

TOC

```
<ol>
    <li><a href="terms-of-service/#copyrights">Copyrights</a></li>
    <li><a href="terms-of-service/#trademarks">Trademarks</a></li>
    <li><a href="terms-of-service/#indemnification">Indemnification</a></li>
</ol>
```

Content

```
<h3 id="trademarks">Trademarks</h3>
    <p> text text text </p>
```

The standard behavior for in-page links is an immediate jump to the content. For a more elegant experience, I added a smooth scrolling effect:

```
$('a[href*="\\#"]').on('click', function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
});
```

Like script #1, this seems to work perfectly.

***However, when both scripts appear together on the page, nothing works properly.***

There are no console errors. The main problem is that the modal script activates the CSS (scrollbar disappears), but doesn't launch the lightbox.

***How can both of these scripts work together?***

Comment: It all looks pretty straightforward.  An element can have numerous click event listeners and the first one simply toggles a class. Can you replicate in a demo?

Comment: Nothing shown is lightbox or modal related

Comment: Launch from where though? And by what mechanism? That's my point. There is no relationship shown.

Comment: @charlietfl The entire lightbox and modal feature is CSS, except for the JS posted in the question. That's why I think it's a conflict between the anchor selectors in the modal and smooth scrolling scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. However, I coded it blindly. If it doesn't work I could use testing it on the live example, to see where it fails. It should work, though. What it does is simple: it skips smooth-scrolling if any of the these have been pressed: (`#contact`, `#email`, `#login` or `#close`).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[href$='#contact'],[href$='#email'],[href$='#login']").click(function(){
    $("body").addClass("noscroll");
  });
  $("a[href$='#close']").click(function(){
    $("body").removeClass("noscroll");
  });    
  $('a[href*="\\#"]').on('click', function(event){
    var href = $(event.target).closest('a').attr('href'), 
        exceptions = ['#contact', '#email', '#login', '#close'], 
        skip = false;
    for (i = 0; i < exceptions.length; i++) {
      if (href.indexOf(exceptions[i]) > -1) {
        skip = true;
      }
    }
    if (!skip) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

**Note.** The above script combines the two scripts you showed in your question and should replace both.

Comment: Glad I could help you back, @Michael_B.

Comment: Hi Andrei, you adjusted a code block for me about a year ago. It works great. Thanks, again. I'm having two minor problems with these same links. If you get a chance, please take a look. I've outlined the problems at the bottom of my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48152914/3597276

Comment: @Michael, I'm not sure I understand the intended behavior. What does *"completely unresponsive"* mean in the context of that question? Could you link anything live? And also: is it possible for you to add a specific class or even an attribute (say rel="lightbox (or modal?)" to links that should prevent default and let the rest go to their target? This way we wouldn't need to guess which case we're dealing with. Modal links open modals, everything else has normal link behavior.

Comment: The code you authored above works fine. All modals work fine. The only problem I'm having is with in-page links, and I think the source of the problem is this JS.

Comment: Why don't fragment identifiers appear in the address bar? Why doesn't a link with a fragment identifier in another page work? Those are the two problems. I've added a bit more detail in the question I referenced (see the bottom half).

Comment: Does adding a `/` in front of the `#` make any difference? Are you saying when you click on `/whatever#hash` you are directed to `/whatever` and the `#hash` part is lost somewhere along the way?

Comment: The site is not live yet. It's a project I'm working on. The link behavior involves several components, including PHP, jQuery and regex (via htacess), so I can't provide a live demo at the moment.

Comment: Q1: No difference. Q2: It's not re-directed to the non-hash URL. It works as intended. But it only shows `/whatever` in the address bar. Yes, the `#hash` part is lost, but the `#hash` function is achieved.

Comment: And it only works inside the `/whatever` page. If I'm on the `/whatever` page and create a link to `/anotherpage/#hash`, that link has no effect... it's totally unresponsive.

Comment: Wait a second, on the `/whatever` page, when you press `/whatever#hash` you want the url to to `/whatever#hash`. Correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162755/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-michael-b).

Answer (score 0):

What does the '\\' on the second script's selector? Having this said, I don't think it is the problem.

As far as I can see, first script is selecting the links by their hrefs starting with a dash character and following four different words.

Second script also selects links contain a dash character in their hrefs.

Normally attached multiple handler to an elements same event should not conflict and they all run. But second script also stops event processing with : event.preventDefault();

I'm assuming this is intended so you need to be more specific on selecting the HTML elements before attaching the event handlers to prevent unwanted behaviours. For example you can modify your second script to be :

```
$("[href$='#copyrights'],[href$='#trademarks'],[href$='#indemnification']").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
});
```

Comment: `\\\` is special character escape in jQuery selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ Not really needed in attribute strings though