# htaccess exception for in-page anchor links

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I use directives in an .htaccess file to clean-up my website URLs.

For instance, this directive adds a trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

and these remove file extensions:

```
# hide .php file extensions
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# redirect .html to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# redirect .htm to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.htm [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```

The problem I'm having is with in-page anchors. When I create a link to a section of page, like this:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/privacy-policy#information-we-collect
```

The system outputs this:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/privacy-policy/#information-we-collect
```

How do I adjust the .htaccess file to make an exception for the trailing slash requirement when it comes to in-page anchor links?

---

A related problem is this:

Although both of these links work:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/privacy-policy#information-we-collect
https://www.mywebsite.com/privacy-policy/#information-we-collect
```

... *when they are inside the page* (Privacy Policy, in this case).

The URL never adjusts in the address bar to show the fragment identifier (`#...`). The address bar stays fixed at:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/privacy-policy/
```

When it would normally adjust to:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/privacy-policy#information-we-collect
```

Lastly, while these links with fragment identifiers work within their page, a link with a fragment identifier to another page, does not work.

So, if I'm on the Privacy Policy page, all these links work fine:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/privacy-policy#information-we-collect
https://www.mywebsite.com/privacy-policy/#information-we-collect
https://www.mywebsite.com/terms-of-service/
```

But this is totally unresponsive:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/terms-of-service#limitation-of-liability
```

It only works within the Terms of Service page.

Comment: A web server (or rewrite rules) don't know anything about anchors because part of URL starting with `#` is completely handled in browser and is not sent to web server.

Comment: `#information-we-collect` part won't be sent to web server so creating an exception for `#...` won't solve the problem. There has to be some other way to create exception e.g. adding a prefix/suffix or a dummy query parameter that rewrite rules can see and take action on.

Comment: Thanks, again. I believe the problem lies elsewhere then, since the links are unresponsive even when coded in pure HTML. I'll have to look at my JS now.

Comment: If you want to post your comments as an answer, I'll accept it. @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comments to an answer.

This exception cannot work:

1. Because a web server (or rewrite rules) don't know anything about anchors because part of URL **starting with** `#` is completely handled in browser and is not sent to web server.
2. `#information-we-collect` part won't be sent to web server so creating an exception for `#...` won't really solve the problem. There has to be some other way to create exception e.g. adding a prefix/suffix or a dummy query parameter that rewrite rules can see and take action on.
3. Alternatively you can handle it on client side itself i.e. inside Javascript code.